# Understanding the conditioning in a GARCH process

Tags: garch, conditional-expectation

In a GARCH model like the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= \sigma_tz_t,\\
\sigma_t^2 &=\omega(1-\alpha-\beta)+\alpha y_{t-1}^2+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2
\end{aligned}
$$
where $z_t$ is assumed to be iidN(0,1), we say that conditional on past information $y_t$ has the Gaussian density
$$f(y_t|y_{t-1},\sigma_{t-1}^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_t}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2_t}y_t^2\right)$$ 
Am I correct in making the following conclusion?

> When conditioning on the past, we know what the value of $\sigma^2_t$ is.
>   Consequently, we can state that $y_t$ is conditionally normally distributed as $N(0,\omega(1-\alpha-\beta)+\alpha y_{t-1}^2+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2)$.

Comment: to make this more clear I recommend stating *what* is being conditioned in the "conditionally normally distributed" statement. For example, conditioning on $y_{t-1}, \sigma^2_{t-1}$ makes your conclusion correct.

Comment: @Sunv: Richard makes a good point and another thing is that, $\sigma^2$ is not observable, so you never know it. You're always estimating it. If this is obvious to you, then apologies for noise.

Answer (score 0):

In the density for $y_t$ you should substitute $\sigma_t$ with its expression above.
Once you have done that, it becomes more transparent that your conclusion holds.

Comment: Thanks. I moved it.